# How to solve , Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information

Tags: node.js, machine-learning, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-automl

I am implementing google automl in NodeJS to predict the image level. I have created model, level and uploaded images manually. Now I want to predict level of an image using NodeJS.
I wrote a function but always getting the below error,

```
Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information
```

the code is below-

```
async function addfile() {
  console.log("add file called")
  const projectId = "project-name";
  const computeRegion = "us-central1";
  const modelId = "modelid";
  const filePath = "./src/assets/uploads/micro.jpeg";
  const scoreThreshold = "0.9";

  const client = new automl.PredictionServiceClient();
  const modelFullId = client.modelPath(projectId, computeRegion, modelId);
  try {
    const content = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'base64');
    const params = {};
    if (scoreThreshold) {
      params.score_threshold = scoreThreshold;
    }
    const payload = {};
    payload.image = { imageBytes: content };
    console.log("try block is running")
    var [response] = await client.predict({
      name: modelFullId,
      payload: payload,
      params: params,
      keyFilename: "./src/assets/uploads/service_account_key.json"
    });
    console.log('Prediction results: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
    response.payload.forEach(result => {
      console.log('Predicted class name: ${result.displayName}');
      console.log('Predicted class score: ${result.classification.score}');
    });
  } catch (exception) {
    console.log("exception occur = " + exception);
  }
}
```

Any solution for that will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you write a Cloud Functions? If not, where your code is running?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have done it  by adding GOOGLE ENVIRONMENT variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Rakesh Saini , this error occurs when [environment variables](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/tutorial) are not set or missing.The environment can be set by adding [application credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production) in the project and adding other required environment variables like Project ID and location.